# How to don't invoke the change notification in a observed property in Polymer?

Tags: properties, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a property ("toggleChecked") changed by a toggle button that must to do some stuff when I press the toggle.
I need to reset the toggle value without invoke the observer function.

```
<dom-module id="custom-element">
<template>
  <paper-toggle-button checked="{{toggleChecked}}">Toggle</paper-toggle-button>
</template>
<script>
  Polymer({
    properties: {
      toggleChecked: {
        type: Object,
        observer: 'toggleCheckedChanged'
      }
    },
    toggleCheckedChanged: function(value) {
      // do some stuff...
    },
    resetToggleChecked: function(value) {
      // change the value, but don't activate the observer function!
      this.toggleChecked = value; // ??
    }
  });
</script>
</dom-module>
```

The "resetToggleChecked" is invoked with an unknown value and I must be sure that the "toggleChecked" is changed without do the "some stuff".
I must do "some stuff" only when I press the toggle with the mouse.

Is there a way to change the property without invoke the observed function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the [documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-toggle-button), `paper-toggle-button`s emit two different change events:

- `change`: Fired when the checked state changes due to user interaction.
- `iron-change`: Fired when the checked state changes.

If you bind a callback to the `change` event only, your callback will only run when the button is toggled actively from user input and *not* just when the underlying value changed.

```
<dom-module id="custom-element">
<template>
  <paper-toggle-button 
    on-change="_onChanged" 
    checked="{{toggleValue}}">Toggle</paper-toggle-button>
</template>
<script>
  Polymer({
    properties: {
      toggleValue: {
        type: Boolean
      }
    },
    _onChanged: function(event) {
      // This is called only when the paper-toggle-button changes 
      // via user interaction. 
      // do some stuff...
    },
    resetToggleChecked: function(value) {
      // This will cause the toggle's checked value to change
      // without triggering the _onChanged handler.
      this.toggleValue = value;
    }
  });
</script>
</dom-module>
```

Edit: corrected wrong line: **on-changed="{{_onChanged}}"** with: **on-change="_onChanged"**

Comment: It's a good solution I didn't mind. I've suggested a correction: it's **on-change** property to use and without double curly braces. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I've been using Polymer since very early on and the syntax changed there so I make that mistake occasionally.